# Flow intellisense not working with higher order components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype, flow-typed

I am using flow types in vscode and have trouble with the intellisense feature when dealing with higher order components, like `connect` from `react-redux` or `withRouter` from `react-router`.

When I want to navigate to the implementation of a component, for example by cmd-right-clicking on the component's name, vscode jumps to the type definition from the flow-typed sources instead of the definition of my implementation.

**Example**

*a.js*

```
// @flow

...

function Child() {
   return <div>This is just a test.</div>;
}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Child)
```

*b.js*

```
// @flow

...

function Component() {
   return <ConnectedChild />;
}
```

When I click `Go to definition` on `<ConnectedChild />`, i expect to jump to `a.js`, but instead vscode jumps to `flow-typed/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x.js`

Any chance to get around this issue? Intellisense works without issues for plain components. I am using latest version of flow (0.117.0), the *Flow Language Support* extension for vscode (issue exists also for other extensions I tested) and disabled the *Typescript and Javascipt Language Features* support built into vscode to rely on flow intellisense only.